# How to access to assets directory with ionic native http?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ngx-translate, ionic5

I have an application developed with ionic 5, to manage http calls on the device I use the native http plugin.
At startup the application must access the assets folder to retrieve the json with the translation of ngx tralslate.
to date I am returning a protocol error from the call.
this is the error text:
There was an error with the request: no protocol: ./assets/i18n/it-IT.json
How do I access the assets folder on the device?
What protocol should I enter?

```
import {Injectable} from "@angular/core";
import {
    HttpErrorResponse,
    HttpEvent,
    HttpHandler,
    HttpInterceptor,
    HttpRequest,
    HttpResponse
} from "@angular/common/http";
import {Observable, throwError} from "rxjs";
import {Platform} from "@ionic/angular";
import {HTTP} from "@ionic-native/http/ngx";
import {catchError, finalize, map} from "rxjs/operators";
import {Store} from "@ngrx/store";
import {hideLoader, viewLoader} from "../loader-store/loader.action";

@Injectable()
export class HttpNativeInterceptor implements HttpInterceptor {
    constructor(
        private platform: Platform,
        private http: HTTP,
        private store: Store<any>
    ) {
    }

    intercept(req: HttpRequest<any>, next: HttpHandler): Observable<HttpEvent<any>> {
        const headers = {};
        const params = {};
        const {method, url} = req;
        this.store.dispatch(viewLoader())
        return (this.platform.is('capacitor') ? this.callNative(url, method, headers, params) : next.handle(req))
            .pipe(
                map((resp: HttpEvent<any>) => {
                    return resp
                }),
                catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
                    return throwError(error);
                }),
                finalize(() => {
                    this.store.dispatch(hideLoader())
                })
            )
    }

    callNative(url, method, headers, params) {
        return new Observable(ob => {
            switch (method) {
                case 'GET':
                    this.http.get(url, headers, params).then(
                        this.successCallback(ob),
                        this.errorCallback(ob)
                    )
                    break;
                case 'POST':
                    this.http.post(url, headers, params).then(
                        this.successCallback(ob),
                        this.errorCallback(ob)
                    );
                    break;
                case 'PUT':
                    this.http.put(url, headers, params).then(
                        this.successCallback(ob),
                        this.errorCallback(ob)
                    );
                    break;
                case 'DELETE':
                    this.http.delete(url, headers, params).then(
                        this.successCallback(ob),
                        this.errorCallback(ob)
                    );
                    break;
            }
        });
    }

    successCallback(ob) {
        return (response: any) => {
            ob.next(new HttpResponse({body: JSON.parse(response.data)}));
            ob.complete();
        };
    }

    errorCallback(ob) {
        return (response: any) => {
            ob.next(new HttpErrorResponse({error: response.error}));
            ob.complete();
        };
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In response to your comment below I am updating my answer:
It seems what you need to do is also add the http-loader helper class from [the ngx-translate project](https://github.com/ngx-translate/http-loader).

There is also a [stack blitz which shows a basic example of implementing this.](https://stackblitz.com/github/ngx-translate/example)

NOTE: This was an easy solution to find with Google -> "ngx-translate with local data"

---

ORIGINAL ANSWER LEFT BELOW FOR HISTORICAL PURPOSES:
This is not an ionic issue or an http issue.

Since the file is local there is no need to use HTTP.

To be able to read json locally add a file called njson-typings.d.ts to your src directory

```
 declare module "*.json" {
  const value: any;
  export default value;
}
```

You can then import that information at the top of your file like so:

```
 import translation from '../assets/i18n/it-IT.json';
```

NOTE: you may have to change relative file path depending on which file you import from.

Within your component itself you would make the import available like so:

```
 Translation: any = translation;
```

You can then reference it either in templates or in code.

REFERENCE: [HOW TO READ LOCAL JSON](https://blog.bitsrc.io/how-to-read-local-json-files-deploy-an-angular-app-a96a881036f2)

Comment: The translations are loaded with the ngx-translate loader which uses a get http to retrieve the file locally.
How can I integrate the import with this file with this mechanism? When I change language how can I tell it to load the second language?
With this solution it seems to me that we need to write a custom translateLoader

Comment: @EmanueleGaleotti I have updated my answer with input from your comment.